# Grails count children of one to many within the domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a one-to-many relationship:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Book {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [author:Author]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I want to be able to count the number of books that belong to an author within the author class such that the resulting generated MySQL table would look like this:

```
id | version | name | bookcount
-- | ------- | ---- | ---------
 1 |       0 | foo  |        15
 2 |       0 | bar  |         3
 3 |       0 | baz  |         7
```

...where bookcount is a defined field in the author class:

```
class Author {
    String name
    int bookcount = ??
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
bookcount must be persisted in the database.

Comment: Do you need this value to be saved in the database? or you just need another way to compute this value ?

Comment: Yes.  It is important to me that "bookcount" is a property of Author, such that it can be accessed with something like authorInstance.bookcount

Comment: You can also get `bookCount` by a method named `getBookCount` in Author class with whatever you are thinking of doing in controller. For example, `Integer getBookCount() { Book.countByAuthor( this ) }`.

Comment: You have a lot of possibility: transient properties (not persisted in the DB), or something like bookcount = author.book ? author.book.size() : 0, or using an interceptor to increase the value in a real field (this one will be a real field in your db)

Comment: This link will help you if you don't need to save the value in the DB: http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html (the implementation will be the same as in the comment of dmahapatro)

Comment: As pointed out you can implement this in a number of ways. However, there are  use cases for persisting this information into the database. In order to persist this information you will need to leverage the Custom Event Listeners for persistence. The reference documentation explains how to create and register them. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using [gorm events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping):

```
class Author {
    String name

    Integer bookCount = 0
    static hasMany = [books:Book]

    Integer getBookCount () {
        books?.size () ?: 0
    }

    void beforeUpdate () {
        bookCount = getBookCount ()
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The `beforeUpdate` method will be called before the object is updated in the database.

The `getBookCount()` property getter makes sure we always get the correct value. If the author is not yet saved after adding more `Book`s, `bookCount` would not be up to date until author is `save()`d.

If we don't use `bookCount` from code we could inline it.

```
def "explicitly persist book count" () {
    given:
    Author author = new Author(name:'author')
    author.save (failOnError: true)

    when:
    author.addToBooks (new Book(name:'book'))
    author.save (failOnError: true, flush: true)

    then:
    author.bookCount == 1
    author.@bookCount == 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way if you don't want to pull all the children out of the database and count them, which could be bad for very large sets of data, is a method like this on the parent class.

```
    def numberOfChildren()
{
    def result = Child.executeQuery("select count(*) from Child where parent = :parent", ["parent":this])
    def resultCount = result[0]
    return resultCount
}
```